# Upgrading ionic 5 to 6 led to this breaking changes :Property 'set' does not exist on type 'Config'

Tags: angular, typescript, button, ionic6, angular-upgrade

Error: src/app/app.component.ts:43:19 - error TS2339: Property 'set' does not exist on type 'Config'.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] 43       this.config.set('backButtonText', this.translateService.instant('button.back'));

and this is the code

```
      this.config.set('backButtonText', this.translateService.instant('button.back'));
```

I updated ionic 5 to 6, Angular version is 13

Comment: based on ionic document https://ionicframework.com/docs/developing/config#global-config, I need to add variable for the text and add to the template. Issue here is I need to add it now for every single component as a prop (@Input)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decleared a variable in app component and using service     `this.dataService.updateBackButtonText('button.back';`
, subscribed each child component.